# Initialization of character array inside constructor (Array Index Out of Bounds) in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, initialization, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to initialise these two character arrays inside a constructor. The error is with the character arrays buf and clientip, the others are fine. I have added the code of the entire constructor below:

```
class server : public udp {

public:
    server() {

        clientLength = 0;
        buf[1024] = {};
        bytesIn = 0;
        count = 0;
        clientIp[256] = {};
        portnumber = 0;
    }

private:
    
    int clientLength = sizeof(client);
    char buf[1024];
    int bytesIn;
    int count = 0;
    char clientIp[256];
    unsigned short portnumber = 70000;
```

The warning is that:

*(error) Array 'buf[1024]' accessed at index 1024, which is out of bounds. [arrayIndexOutOfBounds]

(error) Array 'clientIp[256]' accessed at index 256, which is out of bounds. [arrayIndexOutOfBounds]*

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It told you exactly what the problem is: `buf[1024] = {};` in your constructor is accessing element 1024, which is out of bounds. Remove the [1024]. Better yet, move all of that to the initialization section of the constructor, or assign the default values in the private section.

Comment: @sweenish Thanks alot for your answer. Can you show me in code what you mean for the first part of the solution

Answer (score 1):

`buf[1024] = {};` does not what you want. It will access the 1024th element of `buf` and default initialize just this element, but it is out of bounds.

What you probably want:

```
class server : public udp {

public:
    server() : clientLength(), buf(), bytesIn(), count(), clientIp(), portnumber(){
    }
```

You should always prefer the member initialize list when possible.